# Windows batch script has to accept an input file with a specific extension

Tags: batch-file

How to make a .bat file accept a file which ends in a particular extension from the path of the .bat file? I am new to batch commands.

Eg:
I have to run the following command in bat:
some command inputfile.extension.

File with the extension has to be taken from the path of bat file and this command has to be executed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It depends on what the current directory is when the `.bat` file is invoked. Please provide more information, including that actual command and input file you're wanting to use. Do not provide an answer to this comment as another comment, use the [edit facility](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54017563/edit) instead, remembering to format the code using the **`{}`** button.

Comment: `%0` represents the batch files **d**rive **p**ath **n**ame and e**x**tension, with the `~` modifier you can select just **d**rive and **p**ath `%~dp0`. See `call /?`

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the "0" argument sent to a batch file (`%0`) which is actually like `%~dpnx0`, or even simplified `%~f0`. What you need is the **d**rive letter and the **p**ath only. So, you can try:

```
command %~dp0file.ext
```

or even much more complicated (might won't work if `command.ext` is neither in `PATH` nor in `%~dp0`):

```
pushd %cd%
cd %~dp0
command file.ext
popd
```

> `%~1`         - expands `%1` removing any surrounding quotes (")
>   `%~f1`        - expands `%1` to a fully qualified path name
>   `%~d1`        - expands `%1` to a drive letter only
>   `%~p1`        - expands `%1` to a path only
>   `%~n1`        - expands `%1` to a file name only
>   `%~x1`        - expands `%1` to a file extension only
>   `%~s1`        - expanded path contains short names only
>   `%~a1`        - expands `%1` to file attributes
>   `%~t1`        - expands `%1` to date/time of file
>   `%~z1`        - expands `%1` to size of file
>   `%~$PATH:1`   - searches the directories listed in the `PATH`
>                environment variable and expands `%1` to the fully
>                qualified name of the first one found. If the
>                environment variable name is not defined or the
>                file is not found by the search, then this
>                modifier expands to the empty string
>
> The modifiers can be combined to get compound results:
>
> `%~dp1`       - expands `%1` to a drive letter and path only
>   `%~nx1`       - expands `%1` to a file name and extension only
>   `%~dp$PATH:1` - searches the directories listed in the `PATH`
>               environment variable for `%1` and expands to the
>               drive letter and path of the first one found.
>   `%~ftza1`     - expands `%1` to a DIR like output line

<sup><sup>From `call /?`</sup></sup>